# Math Operators Conditional on Prefix

Tags: macros, math-operators

I want to write some macros whose behavior can change if preceded by a specified macro. Specifically, I have macros controlling notation (math operators like `\det`, `\trace`, etc.) which have counter-parts in another field, they're names are prefixed by "super-", so I was thinking about writing `\super\det`, `\super\trace`, etc. for the super-notation in super-mathematics.

This might also be a horrible idea, but right now I'm just wondering if it's *feasible*.

## Example

I am writing some notes on supermathematics, which is like ordinary mathematics...but *super* (i.e., Z2-graded). We prefix almost everything with "super".

I want something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
% ... amsmath packages omitted, but probably needed

% vanilla mathematical operators
\DeclareMathOperator\tr{tr}
\DeclareMathOperator\det{det}
\def\commutator#1#2{[#1, #2]}

% any operator with "\super" preceding it is defined
% to behave according to the declarations within this body
\prefixRedefs{\super}{
  \DeclareMathOperator\tr{str} % super trace
  \DeclareMathOperator\det{Ber} % super det are called Berezinians
  \def\commutator#1#2{[#1, #2\}}
}

\begin{document}
In Linear algebra, we have $\det(A)$, but super linear
algebra has $\super\det(A)$. Supermatrices may be given
a super commutator $\super\commutator{A}{B}$ and we get
a super Lie algebra; just as normal matrices may be given
the commutator $\commutator{A}{B}$ to produce a Lie algebra.
\end{document}
```

I'd ideally like to get `\super\det` to produce `Ber`, `\super\trace` to produce `str`, etc., as specified by the prefixed environment.

Comment: you could do, but why not simply `\superdet` and `\supertrace`  (internally that's what you will need anyway with `\super` defined so that `\super\zzzz`  expands to `\superzzz`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle an excellent question. I think it's because my mental model of supermathematics is it "super-fies" everything, and I would semantically encode that with a `\super\foobar` type macro. [As to why my mind is so demented, well, that requires more characters ;)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\makesuper}[2]{%
  % #1 = \DeclareMathOperator or \newcommand or \DeclareRobustCommand
  % #2 = macro name
  \expandafter#1\csname super\string#2\endcsname
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\super}[1]{%
  \ifcsname super\string#1\endcsname
    \csname super\string#1\expandafter\endcsname
  \else
    \expandafter\ERROR
  \fi
}

\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{tr}
\newcommand{\commutator}[2]{[#1,#2]}

\makesuper\DeclareMathOperator{\det}{Ber}
\makesuper\DeclareMathOperator{\tr}{str}
\makesuper\newcommand{\commutator}[2]{[#1,#2\}}

\begin{document}

$\det A-\tr A+\commutator{X}{Y}$

$\super\det A-\super\tr A+\super\commutator{X}{Y}$

\super\ddt

\end{document}
```

The last one will produce

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \ERROR

l.30 \super\ddt
```

[image]

Don't use `\def`, even if actually allowed with `\makesuper`.

Comment: A couple remarks. (1) I may be evacuated shortly due to a forest fire, but when it's safe (later today or tomorrow), I'll probably accept this as the answer. (2) This is really helpful, thanks!

Comment: @AlexNelson Oh, my! Best wishes! Take care!